# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. On Google play Console (6B974D92)

Tags: java, android, google-play-console

When I am trying to realease my first app on google play console, all is ok. But when I click the final button "Review release", I get this error: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (6B974D92).

I tried changing the browser, chaging .aab by .apk, nothing works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0k0y.png)

Comment: this question doesn't have anything to do with android studio, right ? no need to add the tag for it then :)

Comment: I'm also getting the same error. I submitted a ticket for this. I hope it gets fixed soon! I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be working now! I refreshed the page and then I was able to submit the app for review.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same error in an account that has over 250 published apps. I think this is an error on Google's side and we cannot do anything but wait and try again later, as they say.

Don't worry, nothing is wrong with your account or your app.

Comment: ok, I thought I was doing something wrong, what bad luck I have, just when I am going to publish my first application.

Answer (score 1):

I discarded all drafts and tried again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the same error. We tried a couple of times. Suddenly it worked at the last attempt. Without any fix. So error definitely from Google side. Google <3

Comment: how much time it takes I've been trying for hours

Answer (score 0):

It works now, it seems that the console had a problem and it is already fixed.